# Windows batch file to make multiple copies of a single file, with each copy being assigned a unique filename

Tags: batch-file

I'm experimenting with [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) and various switch commands, in attempting to create a Windows batch file for making multiple (a set number) copies of a single image file.

I'd like to:
name the file to be copied;
state the number of copies required;
have each copy of the file assigned a unique filename. (eg original file 0001.png, with copies 0001-2.png, 0001-3.png, etc)

Answer (score 35):

```
for /l %A in (1,1,100) do copy "C:\some folder\file.ext" "C:\some folder\file-%A.ext"
```

See `for /?`

In a batch file use `%%A` rather than `%A` at the command prompt.

```
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works very well. You've saved me so much time and effort! Thank you very much!

Comment: What if I want to move each created file to different folders? Folders named like folder-01, folder-02, etc.